# What is the syntax to use React fragments in Reason-React

Tags: reason, reason-react, react-fragment

There is [this old chat](https://reasonml.chat/t/how-to-use-react-fragement/660/5) that suggests writing your own fragment wrapper, but I understand that fragment should now be natively supported.
However I couldn't quickly find the correct syntax for it.

Example of what I'm looking for:

```
<fragment>
  <button label="foo"/>
  <button label="bar"/>
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official [documentation page on reason-react and fragments](https://reasonml.github.io/reason-react/docs/en/jsx-2#fragment).

The syntax for using React fragments in reason-react is this:

```
<>
  <button label="foo"/>
  <button label="bar"/>
</>
```

The terse syntax may be easy to miss if you are looking hard for something like `<Fragment>` (this is what happened to me). I first found the answer in the [release notes for version 0.5.0](https://github.com/reasonml/reason-react/blob/master/HISTORY.md#050)